# If $\alpha\in (0,1]$ and $x_n=\alpha x_{n-1}+(1-\alpha)x_{n-2}$, show that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $x_1$, $x_2$ are arbitary real numbers, $\alpha\in (0,1]$ and  $x_n=\alpha x_{n-1}+(1-\alpha)x_{n-2}$ for every positive integer $n$ (>2), show that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is convergent. (Given $x_1<x_2$)

I cannot rearrange to test convergency. Please help me by solving the problem.

Edit

I want to prove by using the property below:

> If $\{x_{2n}\}$ and $\{x_{2n-1}\}$ converges to same limit $l$ then $\{x_{n}\}$ converges to $l$.

Comment: Hint: consider $x_n-x_{n-1}$

Answer (score 6):

Note that $x_{n+2}\in[x_n,x_{n+1}]$ (or $[x_{n+1},x_n]$). Note also that the length of this interval is
$$\ell_n=|x_{n+1}-x_n|=|\alpha x_n+(1-\alpha)x_{n-1}-x_n|=(1-\alpha)\ell_{n-1}$$

Since $\ell_n\to 0$, apply nested intervals.

Comment: how to use nested intervals and what will be the result

Answer (score 5):

We have $x_n-x_{n-1}=(\alpha-1)(x_{n-1}-x_{n-2})$ so we have $x_n-x_{n-1}=(\alpha-1)^{n-2}(x_2-x_1)$ and hence $$\begin{aligned}x_n-x_{n-1}&=(\alpha-1)^{n-2}(x_2-x_1)\\\\x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}&=(\alpha-1)^{n-3}(x_2-x_1)\\&\vdots\\x_2-x_1&=(\alpha-1)^0(x_2-x_1)\end{aligned}$$ and summing those we get $x_n-x_1=(x_2-x_1)\frac{1-(\alpha-1)^{n-1}}{2-\alpha}$ which implies that $$\color{red}{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\dfrac{x_2+(1-\alpha)x_1}{2-\alpha}}.$$

Comment: Please check the denominator in $\frac{1-(\alpha-1)^{n-1}}{1-\alpha}$ after summing

Comment: Fixed. Thank you for the observation @user1942348

Answer (score 2):

$$x_n-x_{n-1}=(-1)(1-\alpha)({x_{n-1}-x_{n-2})}\\=(-1)^2(1-\alpha)^2(x_{n-2}-x_{n-1})\\=\vdots\\=(-1)^n(1-\alpha)^n(x_1-x_0)$$

Now you can complete

Comment: Thanks. I understand. $x_n-x_{n-1}$ depends on $n=$even or odd. How to conclude convergency. Please help.

Comment: @user1942348 $(1-\alpha)<1\implies (1-\alpha)^n\to ?$

Comment: It goes to zero. But how to check the subsequences $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n-1}$ converges to same limit? How to check they are increasing/decreasing and bounded above/below?

Comment: @user1942348 You are forgetting the $||$ - the **mod** value !

Comment: I think you are telling about cauchy ciretia. I want to use the subsequencial criteria to prove it.

Comment: @user1942348 Okay, first state me, the theorem you want to use.

Comment: If $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n-1}$ converges to same limit $l$ then $x_{n}$ converges to $l$.

Comment: @user1942348 Do you have any problem in seeing that both the even sequence and the odd sequence converge to $0$ ?

Comment: Yes. Please help me so that I can see both the even and odd sequences are convergent and converge to zero.

Comment: @user1942348 The even sequences are of the form $(-1)^{2n}(1-\alpha)^{2n}(x_1-x_0)$ . As $(1-\alpha)^{2n}$ goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, so the even sequence goes to $0$. Similar argument for the odd sequence

Comment: I thnk it is not correct. They don't go to 0.

Comment: @user1942348 Why?

Comment: Look $x_n-x_{n-1}$ goes to zero but $x_n$ does not go to zero. \