# $\langle x_n\rangle $ be a sequence such that $x_{(n+2)}=\frac{(x_{n+1}+ x_{n})}{2} $for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $x_n$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

If $\langle x_n\rangle $ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that $$x_{(n+2)}=\frac{(x_{n+1}+ x_{n})}{2}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N},\ $ let $x_1 <x_2$

then subsequence of odd terms is increasing and subsequence of even terms is  decreasing .But how to prove it mathematically? We have

$$x_{(n+2)}-x_n=\frac{(x_{n+1}- x_{n})}{2}= \frac{(x_{n}- x_{n-2})}{4}$$ How to proceed from here? Any hint please.

Comment: Note I wrote an answer, which I've now deleted since I'm voting to close as a duplicate & I later realized I did a lot more than just give a "hint" as I actually explicitly solved it for you. I showed that, if $x_2 = x_1 + d$, then you have $x_n = x_1 + \frac{\left(J_{n-1}\right)d}{2^{n-2}}$ where $J_n$ are the [Jacobsthal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_number) (also see OEIS [A001045](http://oeis.org/A001045)). I used the closed form of these #'s & took the limit, with the result also given in the other question's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2063735/602049).

Answer (score 0):

(I'm pretty sure that
I and many others 
have done this before
but I'll work it out again.)

If
$x(n+1) = ax(n)+(1-a)x(n-1)
$
where
$0 < a < 2$
then

$\begin{array}\\
x(n+1)-x(n)
&= ax(n)+(1-a)x(n-1)-x(n)\\
&= (a-1)x(n)+(1-a)x(n-1)\\
&= (a-1)(x(n)-x(n-1))\\
\text{so}\\
x(n+k)-x(n+k-1)
&= (a-1)^k(x(n)-x(n-1))\\
\text{and}\\
x(n+k)-x(n)
&=\sum_{j=1}^{k}(x(n+j)-x(n+j-1)\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^{k}(a-1)^j(x(n)-x(n-1))\\
&= (x(n)-x(n-1))\sum_{j=1}^{k}(a-1)^j\\
&= (x(n)-x(n-1))\dfrac{(a-1)-(a-1)^{k+1}}{1-(a-1)}\\
&= (x(n)-x(n-1))\dfrac{(a-1)-(a-1)^{k+1}}{2-a}\\
\text{so}
&\text{putting } n = 1\\
x(k+1)-x(1)
&= (x(1)-x(0))\dfrac{(a-1)-(a-1)^{k+1}}{2-a}\\
&= (x(1)-x(0))(\dfrac{a-1}{2-a}-\dfrac{(a-1)^{k+1}}{2-a})\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$0 < a < 2$,
we have
$-1 < a-1 < 1$
so
$(a-1)^{k+1} \to 0$
and

$\begin{array}\\
x(k+1)
&\to 
x(1)+(x(1)-x(0))\dfrac{a-1}{2-a}\\
&=(1+\dfrac{a-1}{2-a})x(1)-\dfrac{a-1}{2-a}x(0)\\
&=\dfrac{2-a+a-1}{2-a}x(1)-\dfrac{a-1}{2-a}x(0)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2-a}x(1)+\dfrac{1-a}{2-a}x(0)\\
\end{array}
$

This is the case
$a = \frac12$
so

$\begin{array}\\
x(k)
&\to
\dfrac{1}{2-1/2}x(1)+\dfrac{1-1/2}{2-1/2}x(0)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{3/2}x(1)+\dfrac{1/2}{3/2}x(0)\\
&=\dfrac23 x(1)+\dfrac13 x(0)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I made a mistake the first time - I had the sum start at 0 instead of 1. Fairly sure it is correct now.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that $x_n <= x_2$ for all n less than or equal to k then $x_{k+1}=\frac{{x_k}+x_{k-1}}{2} <= \frac{2x_2}{2}=x_2$ so by induction sequence is bounded.Now suppose $x_{n-1} <= x_{n}$ for all n less than or equal to k,then $x_{k+1}=\frac{{x_k}+x_{k-1}}{2} => \frac{2x_k}{2}=x_k$ so by induction sequence is increasing.As it is bounded and increasing it is convergent.

Comment: Induction base is clear in question